# cakephp blank index page, trying to load an empty calender from DHTMLX Scheduler

Tags: javascript, cakephp, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am a fiddling with the CakePHP framework and having an issue getting my page to load an empty calender (DHTMLX scheduler).

Following along with the documentation for DHTMLX scheduler and connector I have everything setup but a blank index page. Looking at the page source, all of the scripts are loading but the init function of the scheduler never fires, thus I get a blank page.

Here is the view in question.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>  
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('/dhtmlx/dhtmlxscheduler'); ?>  
  <?php echo $this->Html->css('/dhtmlx/dhtmlxscheduler'); ?>   
</head>  

<body>
  <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data">
        </div>       
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    scheduler.config.multi_day = true;
    scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
    scheduler.config.first_hour = 5;
    scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2010,7,5),"week");
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: You seem to be outputting *everything* in your view. If you're using a layout (which you should in normal situations), you'll end up with a double `<html><head>` in your page, causing your html to be invalid. Please check the generated output by choosing `view source` in your browser, and read this chapter to understand how CakePHP composes its output using views, elements and layouts: [Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-templates)

Comment: Yeah looking at my page source I have two <head> sections one of which  looks to be cake's default settings for the <head> and css (CakePHP: the rapid development php framework). Let me reread that section to try and understand whats going on. Thanks for looking at my question, this has been a strange transition from java.

Comment: Alright thaJeztah thanks for the help that corrected the issues. Managed to get the calendar to display, now to see if I can get data on it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be outputting *everything* in your view.

If you're using a layout (which you should in normal situations), you'll end up with a double `<html><head>` in your page, causing your html to be invalid.

In most situations, your view should only contain the content for a specific *action* in a controller. General content, including the `<head>` of your HTML should be in the *layout*

Please check the generated output by choosing *view source* in your browser, and read this chapter to understand how CakePHP composes its output using views, elements and layouts: [Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-templates)